# Can't run downloaded Angular project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, angular6

**I have downloaded an angular project from angular.io tutorial when i run this project
it shows error**

**Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\Users\asus\angulario".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\Users\asus\angulario"**

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\asus\\angulario".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\asus\\angulario".
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:132:40)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:99:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Observable.toPromise (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:97:16)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:88:94)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:744:11)
```

project live example https://stackblitz.com/angular/bvypgkmlmdv

Download link https://angular.io/generated/zips/toh-pt3/toh-pt3.zip

Comment: Do you have npm in your system? If not get node js and angular cli. Then run `npm install` in your project folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't installed the node modules.

Kindly run the following command `npm install` and run the application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the node modules first.

For that you need to run `npm i` in the root folder of your downloaded app

(and you need also to have npm installed)

Answer (score 0):

First install NodeJS to your computer, then install npm package manager using global key,

```
npm i npm -g
```

And afer that you can install npm packages depending your package.json file as answered previous message.

```
npm i
```